# Are we using Fubini here?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Consider

> The convolution of two random varaibles $X$
> and $Y$ with laws $\mu$ and $\nu$ respectively is  \begin{align*} \mu
>  *  \nu (A): = \mathbb P[X+Y \in A] = \iint \mathbf{1}_A (x+y) \;d \mu (x) \;d \nu (y) . \end{align*}

I am not sure how one for the second equality.

My thought was that \begin{align*} P \left[X + Y \in A \right] = \int_\Omega 1_{X(\omega ) + Y (\omega )\in A} \;d \mathbb P(\omega ) \end{align*} and there should be some use of fubini here to justify writing it as in the definition? I think I can justify the equality in a more elementary way. I can show that it holds for a generating $\pi $ system and then use Dynkin's lemma. However, I do not think this is trivial. This makes it unlikely to be the right way to do it as this is included in the definition.

Could someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_\Omega 1_{X(\omega ) + Y (\omega )\in A} \;d \mathbb P(\omega )$$ $$=\iint \mathbf{1}_A (x+y) \; \;d(\mu, \nu) (x, y)$$ $$=\iint \mathbf{1}_A (x+y) \;d \mu (x) \;d \nu (y)$$ $$=\iint \mathbf{1}_A (x+y) \;d \nu (x) \;d \mu (y)$$ by change of variables  and Tonelli's Theorem.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. To clarify, the first equality is the change of variables formula. The second and third equalities are due to Tonelli correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. @MathsWizzard

Comment: [In particular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem#Tonelli's_theorem), Fubini assumes the integrand's modulus is integrable, and Tonelli assumes the integrand is non-negative and measurable.